# Display the center of an image using imageview

Tags: android

I have a large image ( Shown Below) in android,i want to show the second image (Shown Below) using imageview in android xml file. Below is my xml.file.

```
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_holder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

1st Image
[image: large picture]

2nd Image

[image: small picture]

my codes above still show the original image, please is there a way to show the second image out from the original image. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solving by setting "android:adjustViewBounds" to "true":

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_holder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```